# What is the Pythonic way to set up in a class a static dictionary that can be modified at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am replacing a static method in a class:

```
class Foo(object):

    @staticmethod
    def num_examples(subset='train'):
        if subset == 'train':
            return 6200
        elif subset == 'validation':
            return 1900
        elif subset == 'test':
            return 1900
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid data subset "%s"' % subset)
```

I would like the num_examples to be in a dictionary that is called by a static method with the same signature as the current num_examples method but that can be initialized at run-time.

```
Foo.num_examples('bar', 86) 
print(Foo.num_examples('bar'))
```

I am using Python 3.x.

Comment: If you want a dict, why are you writing a method? Write a dict.

Comment: @user2357112 Want the method signature in the legacy code to remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, and will always be, a syntax error:

```
Foo.num_examples('bar') = 86
```

You can not assign to a function call in Python.  You'll have to adapt the code to use a dict like it's a dict.

```
Foo.num_examples['bar'] = 86
```

You may still write legacy interfaces for the "getting" part, but the "setting" part can not be done how you're asking.  For providing a legacy interface, you could define and use a "callable dict":

```
import warnings

notset = object()

class MyDict(dict):
    def __call__(self, key, val=notset):
        if val is notset:
            warnings.warn('this syntax is deprecated')
            return self[key]
        else:
            self[key] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dict and put it in the static method using `global`.

```
my_dict = {}
class Foo(object):

    @staticmethod
    def num_examples(subset, value=None):
        global my_dict
        if value:
            my_dict[subset] = value
            return None
        try:
            return my_dict[subset]
        except:
            print("Not found in my_dict")
```

So now this -

```
Foo.num_examples('bar', 86)
print(Foo.num_examples('bar'))
```

Should print `86`

Comment: Thanks.  Edited to eliminate syntax error: Foo.num_examples('bar', 86)

Comment: You could also put the dict into the class

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude my solution works now, according to edit in question.